# Getting Most Recent Data for each field from a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets assume i have a table called VISITS containing the following

- VISIT_DATE (TIMESTAMP)
- HEIGHT (NUMBER)
- WAIST (NUMBER)
- WEIGHT(NUMBER)
- PATIENT_ID (NUMBER)

  VISIT_DATE| HEIGHT | WAIST | WEIGHT | PATIENT_ID

  10/01/2012            | (null)      | 96       | 130 | 44123

  11/01/2012            | 1.74        | (null)  | 120 | 44123

  12/01/2012            | (null)      | (null)  | 150 | 44123

What I need is a sql select statement to get the most recent value for each column but ignoring the null fields so the output I need would be

The WHERE clause would be

```
WHERE PATIENT_ID = 44123 ORDER BY VISIT_DATE DESC LIMIT 1
```

---

```
12/01/2012 | 1.74 | 96 | 150 | 44123
```

As you can see from the output I expect to get from the select I am stepping backwards through each row for the patient until I find a value for each field.

I hope this question is clear and possible, I have searched but haven't found any real solution up to now, this is going to be used to streamline a medical system being used with hospitals and there is about 100 fields the above is just an example of a few fields to get the concept across of what is required.

Comment: That's not a good design and it's going to be difficult to maintain it! if you want to save the history - do it in another table, but keep only one record for each patient (and update it respectively) - it will make your life much easier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create table VISITS 
(
  VISIT_DATE TIMESTAMP
, HEIGHT NUMBER
, WAIST NUMBER
, WEIGHT NUMBER
, PATIENT_ID NUMBER
);


insert into visits values(systimestamp, null, 96, 130, 44123);
insert into visits values(systimestamp, 1.74, NULL, 120, 44123);
insert into visits values(systimestamp, null, NULL, 150, 44123);




select 
  last_visit_date
, height
, waist
, weight
, patient_id
from
(
  select 
    first_value( VISIT_DATE) over( partition by patient_id order by visit_date desc) last_visit_date
  , first_value( HEIGHT ignore nulls) over( partition by patient_id order by visit_date desc) height
  , first_value( WAIST ignore nulls) over( partition by patient_id order by visit_date desc) WAIST
  , first_value( WEIGHT ignore nulls) over( partition by patient_id order by visit_date desc) WEIGHT
  , min(visit_date) over( partition by patient_id)  min_visit_date
  , visit_date
  , patient_id
  from visits

)
where 
  min_visit_date = visit_date
and patient_id = 44123
;
```

Here is [SQLfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1dcb4/1/0)

Comment: Wow your an absolute star it works perfectly thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select a.PATIENT_ID,a.VISIT_DATE,b.HEIGHT,c.WEIGHT,d.WAIST
from
    (select    PATIENT_ID,
              max(VISIT_DATE) as VISIT_DATE 
    from      VISITS
    group by  PATIENT_ID)a
join
    (select PATIENT_ID,HEIGHT from (select PATIENT_ID,HEIGHT 
    from VISITS v
    order by  case when v.HEIGHT is null 
        then to_date('1900/01/01','YYYY/MM/DD') 
                    else v.VISIT_DATE end desc) where rownum=1)b
on a.PATIENT_ID=b.PATIENT_ID
join
    (select PATIENT_ID,WEIGHT from (select PATIENT_ID,WEIGHT 
    from VISITS v 
    order by  case when v.WEIGHT is null 
          then to_date('1900/01/01','YYYY/MM/DD') 
                       else v.VISIT_DATE end desc) where rownum=1)c
on a.PATIENT_ID=c.PATIENT_ID
join
    (select PATIENT_ID,WAIST from (select PATIENT_ID,WAIST 
    from VISITS v
    order by  case when v.WAIST is null 
          then to_date('1900/01/01','YYYY/MM/DD') 
                      else v.VISIT_DATE end desc) where rownum=1)d
on a.PATIENT_ID=d.PATIENT_ID
```

**SQL Fiddle [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d6402/68)**

Comment: I guess this query outputs correct results ONLY if patients always gain weight :)

Comment: In oracle ROWNUM is assigned BEFORE order by so this conditions (ROWNUM=1) in your subqueries make no sense. To get TOP 1 in oracle you should use select with nested subquery. [Here is the Oracle FAQ: How to select TOP N](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_select_the_top_n_rows_from_a_table)

Comment: @valexhome:Thanks for your comment.. I have updated my query..Plz check now

Comment: Still incorrect. This query works for the one patient_ID in a table. What if we have many pathient_Id's. Your subqueries in JOIN select TOP 1 from ALL table REGARDLESS patient_ID and then join with main table on patient_id.

Answer (score 1):

```
select visits2.patient_id,visits2.maxDate,
(  select max(HEIGHT) from visits where visit_Date=
    (select max(visit_date) m from visits l
    where (HEIGHT is not null)
           and
          (l.patient_id=visits2.patient_id)
     )
     and 
     (patient_id=visits2.patient_id)
) HEIGHT,

(  select max(WAIST) from visits where visit_Date=
    (select max(visit_date) m from visits l
    where (WAIST is not null)
           and
          (l.patient_id=visits2.patient_id)
     )
     and 
     (patient_id=visits2.patient_id)
) WAIST,
(  select max(WEIGHT) from visits where visit_Date=
    (select max(visit_date) m from visits l
    where (WEIGHT is not null)
           and
          (l.patient_id=visits2.patient_id)
     )
     and 
     (patient_id=visits2.patient_id)
) WEIGHT


from
(select patient_id,max(visit_date) maxDate 
 from visits group by patient_id) visits2
```

Here is [SQLfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d6402/36)

Comment: What will happen if 2 different records have same visit_date? It throws an error discussing subselect returns more than a row.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh: Just fixed. If this case is possible in Visits table I just added MAX() to all subqueries to handle this case.